# Is there a tool for a web page to allow users create an animation from them uploaded photos with soundtrack?

Tags: html, animation, web, photo-gallery, movie

Can anyone help with this issue?

We need some **free** tool (or maybe some technology) to use it on HTML page. Our site users have photo albums.. Something like gallery. It's already uploaded.

And the main purpose is **to let the users create some animation or even movie from** these **photos** and **add** there **some soundtrack**..

Sountrack could be uploaded directly into this tool.

We thought about html5, Js but it's not reliable and not covertible (we also want this animation be convertible to some video format).

Help! Thanx...